# Remove rows from the data frame that have zeros in more than a 98% of the features

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, attributeerror

```
rowzeros = (traindata == 0).sum(axis=1) #Number of zeros in each row  
rowzeros = pd.DataFrame(rowzeros) #Converting to a dataframe 
[row1, column1] = traindata.shape  #We will use the number of rows in the for loop
for i in range(row1):
    if rowzeros.iloc[i, 0] > .98*row1:  #If >98% values in a row are zero
       traindata = traindata.drop(traindata.index[[i]], inplace=True) #drop the row
print(traindata.shape) #Checking the size of the data frame to confirm
```

I am trying to remove all the rows from the data frame that have more than a predefined number of zeros.
Now i get this error, AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 
'shape'. 
I have seen other posts with the same error but in a different context 
Any help is appreciated